# Specific mutations client separations

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link

I know it is possible to use `apollo-link-ws` to handle subscriptions in client side. Also i created a client which uses standard `http` for running `Queris` and `Mutations`, and uses `WebSocket` for `subscriptions`. But i need to `Pub` ( emit ) some data to server through websocket too. So a way is using only `apollo-link-ws` for all actions ( Query, Mutation ). But is it possible to make decision which Query uses Websocket which one uses standard http client?

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import { split } from 'apollo-link';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
  uri:`http://localhost:8899/graphql`,
  credentials: 'include'
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:8899/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    timeout: 120000,
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({ query }) => {
      const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
      console.table(definition);
      return (
        definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
        definition.operation === 'subscription'
      );
    },
    wsLink,
    uploadLink),
  cache : new InMemoryCache(),

});
```

And i pass the client to `ApolloProvider`.